# Firebird embedded multiple user support

Tags: c#, firebird

I'm trying to create an app that communicate with a Firebird 3.0 embedded database.
I need that two or more of my app instances can connect and edit the same database at the same time.
I had create the connection part and it works.
When I start the first instance it connects correctly, but when I try to access to the database with another app it raise this error: `Error while trying to open file -Impossible to open the file.`
I also had try to connect with different account for example user2 and user1 (manually created with isql) but without results.
I search on google all day but I found nothing.
Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

This is the acutal code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Firebird;

namespace Firebird_multiuser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //private TextBox console = new TextBox();

        Firebird.Firebird conn = new Firebird.Firebird();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            input_box.Text = @"G:\Coding\oribruniv8\Firebird\Firebird_multiuser\test.fdb";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (conn.connect(input_box.Text))
                console.AppendText("Successfully connect to database\n");
            else
            {
                console.AppendText("Error during connection ...\n");
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Firebird class

```cs
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using FirebirdSql.Data.Isql;

namespace Firebird
{
    public class Firebird
    {
        FbConnectionStringBuilder csb = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
        int pageSize = 8192;
        bool forcedWrites = true;
        bool overwrite = true;
        FbConnection conn;

        public Firebird()
        {

            csb.ClientLibrary = **correct path to fbclient.dll**;
            csb.UserID = "sysdba";
            csb.Password = "masterkey";
            csb.ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded;
        }

        public bool create(string path)
        {
            csb.Database = path;
            FbConnection.CreateDatabase(csb.ToString(), pageSize, forcedWrites, overwrite);
            this.conn = new FbConnection(csb.ToString());
            this.conn.Open();

            return this.connection_check();


        }

        public bool connect(string path)
        {
            csb.Database = path;
            this.conn = new FbConnection(csb.ToString());
            this.conn.Open();
            return this.connection_check();

        }

        public void query(string SQLquery)
        {
            this.conn.Open();
            using (var transaction = this.conn.BeginTransaction())
            using (var command = new FbCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = this.conn;
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                command.CommandText = SQLquery;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }

        private bool connection_check()
        {
            if (this.conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want two or more apps to connect to the same database, it is time to consider installing Firebird server instead.

That said, if you are using Firebird 3 embedded, it is possible. By default, Firebird 3 embedded will require exclusive access to the database. This can be changed by making sure there is a `firebird.conf` in the same location as your `fbclient.dll` used by your application, and setting the `ServerMode` setting to `SuperClassic` (or `ThreadedShared`).

Doing this carries a small risk. If the database is shared, then all processes must use the same lock files. By default that is the case, but if applications have different `FIREBIRD_LOCK` environment variable settings, this can corrupt a database as each process will think it doesn't have contenders for its locks.

Comment: Thanks (again), it works, but now when I try to connect with a non-registered user (user wasn't created in users database table) i think I won't be able to connect right? But with a random user and password (no registered in database) I can connect anyway. Why? When I run the command show users in isql it display sysdba and for example user2 with a -, like this: `-user2`

Comment: @TommasoBari Contrary to Firebird server, Firebird embedded will authenticate with any user you specify, and it doesn't check any password. The rule is basically: if you can read and write to the database file, you are allowed to connect using Firebird Embedded. However, you will need to have [granted](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-security-privs.html) appropriate rights to the username to be able to do things in the database.